# Express.js 404 when I give url params via '?'

Tags: node.js, rest, express, curl

I have the follwing application

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express();

// All cals should be application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
app.use(jsonParser);

const path=require('path')
var cwd=process.cwd()

/**
* Append Below here your api endpoints
*/

var Weather=require(path.resolve(cwd,'application/controllers/weather.js'));
var w=new Weather(app);

/**
* Do not append below here your api endpoints
*/

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('Umbrelapp Backend app listening on port 8000!')
})
```

Also I have the following controller:

```
/**
* @param object express The basic express onject that handles the http request
*/
function Weather(express)
{
  var self=this;
  var endpoint='/weather';

  express.use(endpoint,function(req, res,next)
  {
    if(http.preprocess(req,res,next,endpoint))
    {
      switch (req.method) {
        case 'GET':
            self.get(req, res,next);
          break;
        default:
        self.unsupportedAction(req,res,next);
      }
    }
  });

  /**
  * Handler for http Get method
  * @param req The http request
  * @param res The http response
  * @param next The next express.js http handler
  */
  self.get=function(req,res,next)
  {
    console.log(req.params);
    res.send('Hello');
  };

  /**
  * Default handler for unwanted http methods
  * @param req The http request
  * @param res The http response
  * @param next The next express.js http handler
  */
  self.unsupportedAction=function(req,res,next)
  {
    res.status(405);
    res.send('None shall pass');
  }
}

module.exports=Weather;
```

But when I try the following curl command

> curl -X GET -i http://localhost:8000/weather?hello=12; echo

I get the following response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 29
Date: Sat, 19 Nov 2016 18:06:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Cannot GET /weather?hello=12
```

But when I do the following curl:

> curl -X GET -i http://localhost:8000/weather ; echo

I get The following response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5
ETag: W/"5-ixqZU8RhEpaoJ6v4xHgE1w"
Date: Sat, 19 Nov 2016 18:08:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Hello
```

Do you have any idea how can I make work both curl commands at any ammount of parameters given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this worked for me:

```
  express.get(endpoint,function(req, res,next)
  {
    self.get(req, res,next);
  })
  .all(endpoint,function(req, res,next)
  {
    if(http.preprocess(req,res,next,endpoint))
    {
      switch (req.method) {
        //Just ot make sure thet get will execute all
        case http.method.GET:
            self.get(req, res,next);
          break;
        default:
        self.unsupportedAction(req,res,next);
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Defining the endpoint in the following form works for me:

```
var endpoint='/weather?*';
```